# My Application works on Firebase Testing but crashes on Google Play Closing Testing

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, google-play

So my team and I are working on an application that we aim to launch on the Playstore. After updating the application to accommodate API level 33 and converting it to AAB via Android Studio we've come across multiple crashes when we got the app via Playstore but on retesting it via the Firebase app, we are able to successfully complete multiple registration tests.

I've attached the crashlytics extracted from firebase from the crash from the app downloaded from the playstore.

I'm not completely sure what went wrong as everything worked smoothly on Firebase but when we just converted it to AAB to accommodate to the Playstore it now just crashes. Any ideas?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues, java.lang.String, java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
       at com.visa.cbp.sdk.j.b.ﹳ.ᐝ(:5)
       at com.visa.cbp.sdk.j.b.י.ˋ(:20)
       at com.visa.cbp.sdk.j.b.י.ᐝ(:20)
       at com.visa.cbp.sdk.ᵎ$5.onResult(:7)
       at com.visa.cbp.sdk.d.If.Ι(:57)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.visa.cbp.sdk.facade.SNWrapper$2.onComplete(:58)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.1:1)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

We're going to also attempt to revert to API Level 31 rather than API Level 33 since our SDK might only accommodate up to that but I'm not completely sure why it would work via Firebase and not via Playstore if that were the case.